# Load Geofirestore documents results into RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I use `GeoFirestore` to find the nearest location, it worked but I need to load the documents that I got into `RecyclerView`, how can possibly achieve that?

**GeoFirestore method**

```
   private void getNearestEstate(){

    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), 2);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDocumentEntered(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, GeoPoint geoPoint) {

        }
}
```

**load into Rv**

```
   private void dataFetch(Query query,int rvView){


          FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Property> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Property>()
            .setQuery(query, Property.class)
            .build();

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),options.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mAdapter = new DiscoverAdapter(options);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = root.findViewById(rvView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.startListening();
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing, I have no clue how to do it.
this is my first time using GeoFirestore.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear enough, I know how to build and load a regular query into RV. but I don't know how to load data came from Geofire into recyclerView, I will add my code to the question.

Comment: I don't see any use of `GeoFirestore` in your code.

Comment: I didn't because there is no error in it, I add it now.

Comment: I understand now. I'll write you an answer right away.

Comment: I will be very grateful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a `GeoQuery` against a Cloud Firestore database and use `addGeoQueryDataEventListener()`, there are a few methods that must be implemented. As in your example, one of those methods is called `onDocumentEntered()`. As you can see, it has two arguments, the first one being of type `DocumentSnapshot`. This object contains all the locations objects in your range. In order to be able to display those locations, you need to iterate through the `DocumentSnapshot` object and get all locations.

To display all the locations in a `RecyclerView`, you first need to create a list of locations. So when you iterate, add all location objects to a list. Then simply create an adapter and pass that list to it's constructor. Set the adapter to the `RecyclerView` and you are done.

If you thought you can pass the `GeoQuery` to a `FirestoreRecyclerOptions` object, as you normally do when querying a Cloud Firestore database, please note that this is not possible, since GeoQuery class does **not** extend `com.google.firebase.firestore.Query`.